# Не подключается шрифт в IE

Tags: шрифты, internet-explorer, css

На сайте подключены шрифты:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueCyr-Light;
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueCyr-Light.otf?') format('embedded-opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueCyr-Roman;
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueCyr-Roman.otf?') format('embedded-opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: AGLettericaCondL-Regular;
    src: url('../fonts/aGLettericaCondL-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

В хроме всё работает, в ie нет. Почему ? Как исправить ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE требует особого формата для шрифта — EOT (Embedded OpenType)

```
/*только для Internet Explorer*/
@font-face {
font-family: Scriptorama;
src: local("Scriptorama"), url(path-to/Scriptorama.eot);
}
```

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Так, а если у меня шрифт имеется в ttf, где взять его в oet

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, есть онлайн-сервисы. Например, [Webfont Generator][1]

   [1]:http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 1):

Бывает что из-за отсутствия кавычек может не подключится например: вот так не подключится

```
@font-face {
    font-family:fonts;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(fonts/fonts.eot);
    src:url(fonts/fonts.eot?#iefix)format(embedded-opentype),
        url(fonts/fonts.woff)format(woff),
        url(fonts/fonts.ttf)format(truetype),
        url(fonts/fonts.svg#fonts)format(svg);
}
```

а вот так подключится:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:fonts;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(fonts/fonts.eot);
    src:url(fonts/fonts.eot?#iefix)format("embedded-opentype"),
        url(fonts/fonts.woff)format("woff"),
        url(fonts/fonts.ttf)format("truetype"),
        url(fonts/fonts.svg#fonts)format("svg");
}
```